# Indenting Javascript in Vim - Problems with Lambda Functions in Functions

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

I have a problem with javascript indenting in vim.
Everything works great, except that the indenting of inline functions as parameters of a function do not work.
This is a javascript only problem (no html involed).

Example

```
someFunc(function() {
    if(foo) {
        bar;
    } else {
        bar;
    }
});
```

is indented to

```
someFunc(function() { 
        if(foo) { 
        bar; 
        } else { 
        bar; 
        } 
        });
```

Do you have the same problems?
How can I fix that?
I tried some scripts from vim.org but they seem to have the same problem.

A script that emulates TextMates javascript indenting functionality would be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim's built in expression for evaluating javascript indentation is terrible. You can fix it by installing the [Better Javascript Indentation plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2765), or get the [source on github](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) if you prefer to [install your plugins as git submodules](http://vimcasts.org/e/27). Installing this plugin will ease the pain. Each time you press return at the end of a line of JavaScript, your cursor should be positioned with the correct level of indentation. Also, you'll be able to use the `=` command to auto-indent your javascript. Install the plugin - you'll wonder how you got by without it.

Comment: i also enabled filetype plugin on and filetype indent on in my .vimrc. thank you for the wonderful plugin

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using ['cindent'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cindent%27) with JavaScript. You can try using ['smartindent'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartindent%27) instead.

From the docs, what `'smartindent'` does is:

> Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line.  Works for C-like
>   programs, but can also be used for other languages.  'cindent' does
>   something like this, works better in most cases, but is more strict...

You can switch to smartindent by:

```
set nocindent smartindent
```

I tested with your code above and it indents as you expect.

See also: [Indenting source code - Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#.27smartindent.27_and_.27cindent.27)

Comment: Hello Thai, great that it works in your vim. I do not see any difference. I even disabled my .vimrc and disabled plugins but there is no change. I tried it in a *.js file and in an empty buffer. no difference.

Comment: how can i see which indent logic i use in the current file?

Comment: Upvoted; this solved my problem of properly indenting when defining functions inside an object definition with {}.

Comment: @innotune type `:set autoindent? cindent? smartindent?` and it'll tell you their current settings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this problem is to remove any cindent/smartindent/autoindent from your .vimrc and use filetype indent instead (the "set no*" lines aren't necessary, just being pedantic).

```
set nocindent
set nosmartindent
set noautoindent
filetype indent on
```

I was having the same problem, and this is what made vim behave.  This also stopped vim from "unindenting" CSS rules at the colon (:) when typing them into an HTML style tag, my other pet peeve.

vim should set the correct indenting rules if you open/save a file with the *.js extension, but you may need to explicitly set ":set filetype=javascript" if you start editing a new (unsaved) file.

vim's indenting isn't horrible, just misunderstood.  For as many programmers that use it, it'd be hard to believe the default indent rules were really that bad.