# vim javascript indentation inside anonymous self-invoking functions

Tags: javascript, vim, anonymous-function

Indentation doesn't work correctly for javascript files in vim 7.3. It seems that vim doesn't like the curly braces inside open parenthesis. Below is an example of how the curly braces are indented by default in vim.

```
var module = (function()
{

    if (1)
{
}
...
})();
```

I use Allman style indentation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style), and the braces are not indented as necessary - they are not bellow the if. (I know that this indentation style it's not very used for javascript, and there are some other problems, but I'm used to it)

As a workaround I use the following syntax which seems to work:

```
var module = function()
{
    if (1)
    {
    }
    ...
}();
```

Do you have the same problem? Is there a solution to fix this?

EDIT:
I tried the Better Javascript Indentation plugin (latest sources from github - https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript), but it seems to work only for K&R style.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I did not get your point...

Comment: @gustavotkg I added more info

Comment: Maybe this accepted anwser will do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326686/indenting-javascript-in-vim-problems-with-lambda-functions-in-functions